# Post array always empty on CodeIgniter application running on nginx

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

I have nginx 1.0.2 installed on Ubuntu 11 with php 5.3.5 running with FPM/FastCGI.

On a codeigniter applilcation of mine i get the following problem. 
I have a simple login form with a username and password field. When I submit the form the $_POST array is empty. So is $this->input->post('username') and $this->input->post('password').

The application works fine on apache. I tried creating a simple test form on a simple php file and $_POST data worked perfectly. I can provide configuration files if needed. Any ideas ?

**Update**:
It finally worked. There were some redirects in my vhost config which were causing loss of post data. The working vhost config can be found here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/90231/#455528

Comment: Do you have fastcgi_pass_request_body off; anywhere in your config?  Is there anything in the error log about failing to open a temporary file for the request body?

Comment: No, fastcgi_pass_request_body is not found in any config or vhost file. I don't get such a "temporary file" error in the log but I do get a 404 error header from the form's target URL. 

/user/login/ displays the form and the same controller/method parses the results as well. However the 404 is in the header only when the form is submited. I guess a redirect rule causes the error. I used the redirect rules from this guy http://bit.ly/kljKty
The rest of nginx configuration is just the default stuff.

To be honest I'm not that deep into redirect rules to make sense of every line in that config.

Comment: You're getting a 404?  How are you verifying that the fields are empty?  A 404 sounds more like the form isn't getting processed at all.

Comment: Through firebug. With print_r($_POST); The form is processed but the validation fails since $_POST is empty. Could you share a working vhost configuration (if you got one) of a codeigniter project through a pastebin or something ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the issue now.  The fact that it's returning 404 and processing your script tells me that the error_page is what's doing the 'rewrite' to get the request to /index.php.  An error_page to a non-named location will transform the request into a GET, so the error_page 404 /index.php is doing an internal redirect to /index.php, but it's stripping the request body in the process (and the lack of an = means the status code isn't overridden by the error_page target).  I'm not sure why all those ifs aren't performing the redirect (if processing in nginx is really weird, so it's a good idea to avoid them), but I think if you use a named location for your error page, that will preserve the request body and fill in $_POST.  Try replacing your current error_page directive with:

```
location @redir {
  rewrite ^ /index.php;
}
error_page 404 = @redir;
```

Comment: It worked a bit. I don't get the 404 now. Yet the $_POST array is still empty

Answer (score 0):

check these:

```
<form method="post">
```

you using the post method?

try running the profiler:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

seeing any POST output there?

Comment: Of course i'm using the post method. Like I said above the app works fine on apache. 

The profiler was a nice idea I havn't thought of but still gives me "No POST data exists".

Answer (score 0):

I was using my own PHP framework with similar URI rewrites as CI and on Nginx server had similar issues, cause my forms had actions like: action="admin/login/post" and I had to change them to end with .php action="admin/login/post.php" so they could work, but this requires you to change the URI rewrite of your CI class to replace that .php from the uri string.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i tried everything mentioned here. It was very simple when i figured it, I had not named my input variables in the form. I had missed the name parameter.

```
<input type="name" placeholder="Name" name="name">
```