# Nginx + phpFPM | DEBIAN 10 | PATH_INFO is always empty

Tags: php, nginx, fpm, debian-buster, pathinfo

I've already looked at the proposed solutions on stackoverflow and I didn't find anything that solved my problem:

- [Nginx + phpFPM: PATH_INFO always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848899/nginx-phpfpm-path-info-always-empty)
- [PATH_INFO in $_SERVER always empty - NGINX + FPM 7.3 + Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640592/path-info-in-server-always-empty-nginx-fpm-7-3-ubuntu-18-04)
- [Nginx config rewrite with PATH_INFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019954/nginx-config-rewrite-with-path-info)
- [nginx path_info in alias environemnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128245/nginx-path-info-in-alias-environemnt)
- [Empty value to PATH_INFO in nginx returns junk value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265941/empty-value-to-path-info-in-nginx-returns-junk-value)
- [Nginx: Hide .php extension but take PATH_INFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229573/nginx-hide-php-extension-but-take-path-info)
- [Debian 9 + PHP7.0-FPM + NGINX 1.10.3-1 path_info issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991666/debian-9-php7-0-fpm-nginx-1-10-3-1-path-info-issue)
- [Post array always empty on CodeIgniter application running on nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049544/post-array-always-empty-on-codeigniter-application-running-on-nginx)

The problem is that the PATH_INFO is still empty

The request it's ok like this: route-php.local/show

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

```php
/home/niko/web/www/route-php.local/public/index.php:46:
array (size=42)
....
'PATH_INFO' => string '' (length=0)
'QUERY_STRING' => string '' (length=0)
....
/home/niko/web/www/route-php.local/public/index.php:51:
array (size=1)
'_route' => string 'show' (length=4)
```

but it's not good with this request: route-php.local/show?p=test

```php
/home/niko/web/www/route-php.local/public/index.php:46:
array (size=42)
....
'PATH_INFO' => string '' (length=0)
'QUERY_STRING' => string 'p=test' (length=6)
....
```

The path is not recognized because it is empty...? Why ?

$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']

with: route-php.local/show

```php
/home/niko/web/www/route-php.local/public/index.php:46:
array (size=42)
....
'PATH_INFO' => string '' (length=0)
'QUERY_STRING' => string '' (length=0)
....
/home/niko/web/www/route-php.local/public/index.php:51:
array (size=1)
'_route' => string 'index' (length=4)
```

### Here's my setup :

PHP-7.4 with composer and I installed symfony/routing

https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/routing

```sh
/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini
    
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1  # And I tried   cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

```sh
/etc/nginx/sites-available/route-php.local

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) { 
        root /var/www/localhost;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
}
```

```sh
snippets
/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf

fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $path_info;  # or fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

I tried several solutions but nothing works ....

example config Symfony : https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

My code PHP:

```php
## index.php ##

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$listeRoute = new Route("/");
$createRoute = new Route("/create");
$showRoute = new Route("/show");

// COLLECTION ROUTES
$collection = new RouteCollection();
$collection->add("list", $listeRoute);
$collection->add("create", $createRoute);
$collection->add("show", $showRoute);

//MATCHER
$matcher = new UrlMatcher($collection, new RequestContext());

var_dump($_SERVER);

$pathInfo = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';

$resultat = $matcher->match($pathInfo);
var_dump($resultat);
die();
```

another Example:

```sh
php -
    |-index.php
    |-text.php
```

```php
#index.php
var_dump($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
echo "index.php";
#test.php
var_dump($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
echo "test.php";
```

```sh
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
```

```sh
location / {try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri.php$is_args$args;}
location ~ \.php {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php7.3-fpm.sock
}
```

```sh
#localhost/index
string(0) ""
index.php

#localhost/test
string(0) ""
test.php
```

Why it behaves like this ?

I would like this behavior

```php
<?php

echo "PATH INFO => ";
var_dump($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);

echo "<br>";

echo "REQUEST_URI => ";
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);


// redefine the variable PATH_INFO
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

echo "<br>";
echo "NEW - PATH INFO => ";
var_dump($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'][0]);

echo "<br>";
echo "index.php";
```

```sh
# https://localhost/index?test=test

PATH INFO => string(0) ""
REQUEST_URI => string(16) "/index?test=test"
NEW - PATH INFO => string(6) "/index"
index.php
```

Comment: The path info is that part of a URI that follows `.php`. Your requested URI does not contain a `.php` so there is no path info. In fact, the URI is internally redirected to `/index.php` which also does not contain a path info.

Comment: I only have an index.php file

Comment: I think this is an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve with the PATH_INFO?

Comment: @JulienB. I answered you on the post and I just installed on the server: nginx, apache2 (listen 8080), php, php-fpm, git, vim, and nothing else.